# Errors Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path AND Syntax error in SQL statement

Tags: java, spring-boot, postman

I'm following a course, and instead of giving error 200, it gives Internal Server Error 500 in postman when i change the fixed user by this method in UserResource :

> return ResponseEntity.ok().body(service.findById(id));

Errors after sending a GET /user/1 request in postman on terminal:

```
ERROR 19448 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not prepare statement; SQL [select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.email as email2_0_0_, user0_.name as name3_0_0_, user0_.password as password4_0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not prepare statement] with root cause

org.h2.jdbc.JdbcSQLSyntaxErrorException: Syntax error in SQL statement "select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.email as email2_0_0_, user0_.name as name3_0_0_, user0_.password as password4_0_0_ from [*]user user0_ where user0_.id=?"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.email as email2_0_0_, user0_.name as name3_0_0_, user0_.password as password4_0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=? [42001-214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:502) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getJdbcSQLException(DbException.java:477) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.message.DbException.getSyntaxError(DbException.java:261) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readIdentifier(Parser.java:5656) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTablePrimary(Parser.java:1814) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.readTableReference(Parser.java:2334) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelectFromPart(Parser.java:2772) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseSelect(Parser.java:2878) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryPrimary(Parser.java:2762) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryTerm(Parser.java:2633) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBody(Parser.java:2612) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpressionBodyAndEndOfQuery(Parser.java:2605) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQueryExpression(Parser.java:2598) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parseQuery(Parser.java:2567) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parsePrepared(Parser.java:724) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:689) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.parse(Parser.java:661) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.command.Parser.prepareCommand(Parser.java:569) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareLocal(SessionLocal.java:631) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.engine.SessionLocal.prepareCommand(SessionLocal.java:554) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareCommand(JdbcConnection.java:1116) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcPreparedStatement.<init>(JdbcPreparedStatement.java:92) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at org.h2.jdbc.JdbcConnection.prepareStatement(JdbcConnection.java:288) ~[h2-2.1.214.jar:2.1.214]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection.prepareStatement(ProxyConnection.java:337) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyConnection.prepareStatement(HikariProxyConnection.java) ~[HikariCP-4.0.3.jar:na]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$5.doPrepare(StatementPreparerImpl.java:149) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl$StatementPreparationTemplate.prepareStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:176) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.StatementPreparerImpl.prepareQueryStatement(StatementPreparerImpl.java:151) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.prepareQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:198) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeQueryStatement(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:162) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.plan.exec.internal.AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.executeLoad(AbstractLoadPlanBasedLoader.java:104) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.loader.entity.plan.AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.load(AbstractLoadPlanBasedEntityLoader.java:285) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.doLoad(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4521) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.load(AbstractEntityPersister.java:4511) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.loadFromDatasource(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:571) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:539) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.load(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:208) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.proxyOrLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:327) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.doOnLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:108) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener.onLoad(DefaultLoadEventListener.java:74) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:118) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoadNoChecks(SessionImpl.java:1231) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.fireLoad(SessionImpl.java:1220) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.access$2100(SessionImpl.java:202) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.doLoad(SessionImpl.java:2835) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.lambda$load$1(SessionImpl.java:2812) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.perform(SessionImpl.java:2768) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl$IdentifierLoadAccessImpl.load(SessionImpl.java:2812) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3400) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.find(SessionImpl.java:3367) ~[hibernate-core-5.6.10.Final.jar:5.6.10.Final]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:362) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy95.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.SharedEntityManagerCreator$SharedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(SharedEntityManagerCreator.java:311) ~[spring-orm-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy95.find(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.SimpleJpaRepository.findById(SimpleJpaRepository.java:335) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker$RepositoryFragmentMethodInvoker.lambda$new$0(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:289) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.doInvoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:137) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryMethodInvoker.invoke(RepositoryMethodInvoker.java:121) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition$RepositoryFragments.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:530) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryComposition.invoke(RepositoryComposition.java:286) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$ImplementationMethodExecutionInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:640) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.doInvoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:164) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.java:139) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.projection.DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMethodInvokingMethodInterceptor.java:81) ~[spring-data-commons-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:123) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:388) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:137) ~[spring-tx-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.support.CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor$CrudMethodMetadataPopulatingMethodInterceptor.invoke(CrudMethodMetadataPostProcessor.java:174) ~[spring-data-jpa-2.7.2.jar:2.7.2]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215) ~[spring-aop-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy98.findById(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at com.example.api.services.impl.UserServiceImpl.findById(UserServiceImpl.java:19) ~[classes/:na]
    at com.example.api.resources.UserResource.findById(UserResource.java:23) ~[classes/:na]
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DirectMethodHandleAccessor.invoke(DirectMethodHandleAccessor.java:104) ~[na:na]
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:577) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1070) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53) ~[tomcat-embed-websocket-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.FormContentFilter.doFilterInternal(FormContentFilter.java:93) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.22.jar:5.3.22]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833) ~[na:na]

Hibernate: select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.email as email2_0_0_, user0_.name as name3_0_0_, user0_.password as password4_0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=?
2022-08-07 16:36:23.499  WARN 19448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 42001, SQLState: 42001
2022-08-07 16:36:23.500 ERROR 19448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Syntax error in SQL statement "select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.email as email2_0_0_, user0_.name as name3_0_0_, user0_.password as password4_0_0_ from [*]user user0_ where user0_.id=?"; expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, user0_.email as email2_0_0_, user0_.name as name3_0_0_, user0_.password as password4_0_0_ from user user0_ where user0_.id=? [42001-214]
2022-08-07 16:36:23.500  INFO 19448 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.e.internal.DefaultLoadEventListener  : HHH000327: Error performing load command
```

User:

```
package com.example.api.domain;


import lombok.*;

import javax.persistence.*;
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Integer id;
    private String name;

    @Column(unique = true)
    private String email;
    private String password;
}
```

UserRepository:

```
package com.example.api.repositories;

import com.example.api.domain.User;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Integer> {
}
```

UserResource:

```
package com.example.api.resources;


import com.example.api.domain.User;
import com.example.api.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PathVariable;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RestController;

@RestController
@RequestMapping(value = "/user")
public class UserResource {

    @Autowired
    private UserService service;

    @GetMapping(value = "/{id}")
    public ResponseEntity<User> findById(@PathVariable Integer id) {
        return ResponseEntity.ok().body(service.findById(id));


        //return ResponseEntity.ok().body(new User(1, "Test", "teste@mail.com", "123")) Only works this way; 

        //User obj = this.service.findById(id);
        //return ResponseEntity.ok().body(obj);
    }
}
```

UserServiceImpl:

```
package com.example.api.services.impl;

import com.example.api.domain.User;
import com.example.api.repositories.UserRepository;
import com.example.api.services.UserService;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import java.util.Optional;

@Service
public class UserServiceImpl implements UserService {

    @Autowired
    private UserRepository repository;

    @Override
    public User findById(Integer id) {
        Optional<User> obj = repository.findById(id);
        return obj.orElse(null);
    }
}
```

UserService:

```
package com.example.api.services;

import com.example.api.domain.User;

public interface UserService {
    User findById(Integer id);
}
```

Comment: please post your full error message

Comment: just a tip for the future, always post your full error message from the beginning. There is no reason at all to not do it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look in your error message you can see that there is a little asterisk `[*]` in it. This asterisk marks out where your syntax error is.

```
Syntax error in SQL statement 

"select user0_.id as id1_0_0_, 
    user0_.email as email2_0_0_, 
    user0_.name as name3_0_0_, 
    user0_.password as password4_0_0_ 
from 
    [*]user user0_ where user0_.id=?"; 
     ^ 
     Here

expected "identifier"; SQL statement:
```

This gives you a hint. Why can't i select from the table `User`? You haven't disclosed explicitly  what database you are using but `User` is quite a common name.

I can guess from the logs that you are using `H2` and they have a complete list of [reserved keywords](http://www.h2database.com/html/advanced.html#keywords) that you are not allowed to use and on that list you can find the name `User`.

So your solution is to probably rename your table to maybe `Users`?

Comment: It works! thank you very much
So, i was seeing an outdated java, because he was using the word User and it was working

Comment: if you feel this answer helped you please mark it as answered

Comment: Tip: The SQL standard specially promises to never have a keyword that ends in a trailing underscore. So, if you always **append a trailing underscore** on all your table names, column names, and other identifiers, you will never have to worry about this keyword versus naming collision. I have counted over a thousand (!) keywords and reserved words across several database products. So it is quite easy to collide with names you would never intuit as being a database keyword.

Comment: I'll do that, thanks for the tip